# Сохранение состояний выполнения операции Java

Tags: java, ui

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть web интерфейс, который загружает через UI в браузере файл. Файл на сервере валидируется, парсится и уже на основе данных из файла создаются сущности в базе. Сейчас реализовано так: в процессе выполнения кода, в базу сохраняется статус выполнения, это нужно для UI, который постоянно запрашивается статус и показывает анимацию выполнения в браузере.

**Вопрос**. С помощью чего и каких технологий и в какую сторону копать, чтобы избавится от сохранения состояний в базу. То есть нужен механизм на Java, с помощью которого можно будет узнавать статус этой операции либо результат выполнения. Или вообще подскажите как это грамотно делается, когда есть какая то относительно долгая операция, и чтобы не блокировать UI мы должны где-то сохранять состояния выполнения.

Comment: Можете не хранить в базе данных, а только в памяти сервера, но тогда есть опасность потерять эти данные. Вариант с хранением состояния в базе хороший, можно и, например, прогресс обработки там хранить. А так, не понятно связь между данными на сервере и блокированием UI. Для фронта можно показывать обработку не блокируя UI, например в каком-нибудь setInterval через ajax обрашивая сервер и показываю статус/результат выполнения

Comment: А что вас пугает в сохранение состояния в базе? Вполне хороший и рабочий вариант. Как альтернатива могу предложить передавать состояние по вебсокету.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Просто таких операции может быть много, и просто не хотелось бы засорять базу. Поэтому думаю нужно продумать какой то механизм, который будет чистить старые записи, давно отработавших операций. Может думаю подключить вместо Oracle Redis и настроить время жизни таких записей